# Magento - Remove blocks from footer on CMS page

Tags: xml, magento, block, footer

In my magento store I have the recently viewed products block and newsletter signup block inside my footer as shown with the below code all working ok:

footer.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('reports/product_viewed')->setTemplate('reports/product_viewed.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer.newsletter') ?>
```

On one of my CMS pages i want to hide these 2 blocks. In the design admin tab for my CMS page i have already hidden the breadcrumbs with the below in the `Custom Layout Update XML` section, again working fine:

```
<reference name="root">
    <remove name="breadcrumbs" />
</reference>
```

I cannot seem to come up with the correct code to remove these blocks. I have tried several lines of code for each block:

```
<reference name="footer">
    <remove name="reports.product.viewed" />
</reference>

<reference name="root">
    <remove name="footer.reports.product.viewed" />
</reference>

<reference name="footer">
    <action method="unsetChild"><alias>reports.product.viewed</alias></action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below code in your layout XML file

```
<cms_page>
    <reference name="footer">
        <remove name="footer-product-viewed" />
        <remove name="your_footer_newsletter_block_name" />
    </reference>
</cms_page>
```

Code in your `footer.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('reports/product_viewed', 'footer-product-viewed')->setTemplate('reports/product_viewed.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer.newsletter') ?>
```

If your footer newsletter block is still not removed try passing `false` parameter, which will not allowed the block to render from cache.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer.newsletter', false) ?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this allowed me not to show the newsletter but have since found out that because the recently block is inside a template, it gets called after the layout file. By checking the the cms page identifier with `$identifier = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier()` and the above i get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Check if CMS page:

```
$page = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page');
if ($page->getId()) {

}
else{

<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('reports/product_viewed')->setTemplate('reports/product_viewed.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer.newsletter') ?>

}
```

**OR**

```
if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms')
{
  // CMS page
}
else{

// your code 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

System menu -> Configuration -> Advanced button under the Advanced section on the left. -> find Mage_Newsletter drop-down menu to Disable -> Click Save

From https://briansnelson.com/How_to_Disable_Magento_Newsletter_Module